# How to add spinner/loader in yii2 php

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, spinner, yii2-advanced-app

I want to add a spinner/loader in one of my forms. The scenario is simple: When I hit the `create` button then it will show a spinner/loader. On hitting the create button a call to a web-service is made so the spinner/loader will show from call start to call end.

Below is my controller:

```
$m = MetersInventoryStore::findOne($_REQUEST['selected_meters']);
$msn = $m->meter_serial; // current selected meter serial number is saved

$date_time = str_replace(' ', 'T', date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); // current date time

$api_url = 'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7000/api/meters/GetByMsn/' . $msn . '/' .$date_time; // my base URL

$curl = curl_init($api_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization:key'));

$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
$json = json_decode($curl_response);
$meter_alive = $json->data->Response;
.
.
.
.
// my other code that is saving data
.
.
.
.
return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model,]);
```

The submit button is below:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Verify Communication' : 'Update', ['id'=> 'spin','name'=>'create','class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-success']) ?>

</div>
```

As told above when I press the `Verify Communication` button a call is made to the web-service and during this time I want to show a spinner/loader.

For creating/showing a spinner/loader I have searched many articles.

1. [Show Loading](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-showloading/)
2. [Kartik Spinner](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-spinner)
3. [Submit Spinner](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-submit-spinner/)
4. [Yii2 Model Loader](https://packagist.org/packages/alesar/yii2-widget-modal-)
5. [Yii2 Jquery Loading](https://packagist.org/packages/loveorigami/yii2-jquery-loading)

But none of the above articles have mentioned the full implementation details. Although I have tried each and every step mentioned in the articles.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of on the submit button why not put the loader on each page load. This can be done by making changes in main layout.

```
<style>
        /*loader css*/

#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

/* Add animation to "page content" */
.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
}

@keyframes animatebottom { 
  from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
}



</style>
```

Add script for function.

```
<script>
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 0000);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("container").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Finally, call the function by binding onload function with body.

```
    <body onload="myFunction()">
        <div id="loader"></div>
<section id="container" style="display:none;" class="animate-bottom">
</section>
    </body>
```

Comment: why do you think a simple form submission will allow the user to show the view or the scripts/css loaded in that view before the `$this->render()` is called? you havent understood the question

Answer (score 0):

No validation on user request

```
$m = MetersInventoryStore::findOne($_REQUEST['selected_meters']);
```

it's too much

```
$msn = $m->meter_serial;
```

do this

```
$api_url = 'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7000/api/meters/GetByMsn/' . $m->meter_serial . '/' .$date_time;
```

Curl request need to be moved to separated method

```
function curlRequest(msn) {
  $api_url = 'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7000/api/meters/GetByMsn/' . $msn . '/' .$date_time; // my base URL
  $curl = curl_init($api_url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization:key'));
  $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
  $json = json_decode($curl_response); // WTF snake case only in Python

  return $json->data->Response;
}
```

And now answer to your question
You need add click event to your button. You using Yii2 his have jQuery for more powerful DOM-tools. Use $.hide() and $.show() for you button class and draw preloader. You can use Promise if you need feedback from server of his save data.