# Adding a loader/spinner to yii2 interface

Tags: ajax, yii2, spinner, loading, yii2-advanced-app

I have a view in which I have two buttons. While clicking on any of the two buttons, a certain request is made.

**View**

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
        <?=Html::beginForm(['process'],'post');?>
        <?=Html::submitButton('Disconnect', ['id'=>'d','name'=>'dco','class' => 'btn btn-primary']);?>
        <?=Html::submitButton('Connect', ['id'=>'r','name'=>'rco','class' => 'btn btn-info']);?>
        <br><br>
        <div class="pre-scrollable">
        <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [


        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn', 'checkboxOptions' => function($d) {
            return ['value' => $d['msn']];
        }],


        'customer_id',
       // 'dept_code:ntext',
        'dept_name:ntext',
        'sub_div_name',
        [
            'label' => 'Sub Division Name',
            'value' => function ($d) {
                return $d->subdiv->name;
            },
            'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'sub_div_code', \common\models\SurveyHescoSubdivision::toArrayList(), ['prompt' => "Sub-Div", 'class' => 'form-control']),

        ],
        'division_name',
        'allowed_units',
        'msn',

        'units_consumed',
        [
            'label' => 'Disconnected',
            'attribute' => 'disconnected',
            'format'=>'raw',
            'contentOptions' => ['style'=>'text-align:center'],
            'value' => function($model){
                return $model->disconnected == 1 ? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>' : '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger"></span>';
            },
            'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'disconnected', [''=>'All','1'=>'Yes','0'=>'No'], ['class' => 'form-control']),
        ],


        'active_energy_total_m',


        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
        </div>
        <?= Html::endForm();?>
        <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

**Controller**

```
 public function actionProcess()
{

 $soapUrl = "http://ip:port/HES/services/Request";
    $userName = "user";
    $password = "123456";

 if (isset($_POST['dco'])) 
    {
        if(Yii::$app->request->isPost)
        {
            $data = Yii::$app->request->post('selection'); //checkbox (array)


            foreach($data as $value)
            {

                $msn = $value;


                $xml_post_string = /** @lang text */
                    '//soap request';

                $headers = array(
                    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                    "Accept: text/xml",
                    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                    "Pragma: no-cache",
                    "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
                ); //SOAPAction: your op URL

                $url = $soapUrl;

                // PHP cURL  for https connection

                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

                // converting
                $response = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                $domd=new DOMDocument();

                var_dump($response);
                if(!$domd->loadXML($response)){
                    throw new \RuntimeException("failed to parse XML!");
                }
                $inner_xml=$domd->getElementsByTagName("return")->item(0)->textContent;
                if(!($domd2=@DOMDocument::loadXML($inner_xml))){
                    throw new \RuntimeException("failed to parse inner_xml!");
                }
                $AsyncReplyFlag=$domd2->getElementsByTagName("AsyncReplyFlag")->item(0)->textContent;

                if ($AsyncReplyFlag =='true')
                {
                    $ds = 1;

                    $disconnected_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                    try {
                        Yii::$app->db->createCommand(/** @lang text */
                            "update 
  `accurate_mam`.`daily_log` 
set
  `disconnected` = '$ds',
  `diconnected_at` = '$disconnected_at', 
  `reconnected_at` = NULL
where `msn` = '$msn' ;

")->execute(); //update master table

                        Yii::$app->db->createCommand(/** @lang text */
                            "update 
                        `accurate_mam`.`log_disconnected` 
                         set

                        `disconnected_at` = '$disconnected_at' 
                         where `msn` = '$msn'")->execute();// update log disconnected table
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                    } // updating the master table
                }


            }

        }
    }
    }
```

**What I want to do?**

On button click, I want to show a spinner/loader that will start when the request is made and stop when the request is completed.

**Note**

I don't want to add a default time for spinner/loader. It should starts when the request is sent and stop when it's completed i.e. when the process is completed

I have searched many articles but can't find the complete implementation details.

**Update 1**

I have found a solution [here](http://www.marcorpsa.com/ee/t2228.html) and tried to implement it by doing the following

```
<style>
#loader {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) url("<?php \yii\helpers\Url::to('@web/images/25.png', true);  ?>") no-repeat center center;
    z-index: 10000;
}
</style>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

      $('form').submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();      

        spinner.show();
        $.ajax({
            url:'$url',
            data: $(this).serialize()
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON'
        }).done(function(resp) {
            spinner.hide();
          //alert(resp.status);
        });

  });      


});
```

**Problem Facing**

Now I am able to see a spinner but the process is not completed. After further debugging, I observed that I am getting `bool(false)` in `var_dump(isset($_POST['dco']));
        die();` while submitting the request

**Update 2**

I have found one more [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38498455/8919244) and tried to do the same

1. Updating both buttons

   ```
   <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp;Disconnect'), ['class' => 'btn red', 'name' => 'dco', 'value' => '0']) ?>
   <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;Connect'), ['class' => 'btn blue', 'name' => 'rco', 'value' => '1']) ?>
   ```

**JS**

```
 $('form').submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        var strValue = "";        
    $('input[name="selection[]"]:checked').each(function() {

    if(strValue!=="")
        {
        strValue = strValue + " , " + this.value;

        }
    else 
       strValue = this.value;     

});


        spinner.show();
        $.ajax({
            url:'$url',
            data: {data :strValue},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON'
        }).done(function(resp) {
            spinner.hide();
          //alert(resp.status);
        });

  });
```

**Controller**

```
if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {

   if (Yii::$app->request->post('dco') == 0) {
    //Code for value 0
 }

   if (Yii::$app->request->post('rco') == 1) {
    //Code for value 1
  }

 }
```

**Problem Facing**

When I click any of the two buttons it always hit the `dco` check i.e. `if (Yii::$app->request->post('dco') == 0)` it's not hitting the `rco` condition

There must be something that I am missing.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: as far i understand its a normal form `submit` button which is submitting the form to the action, pjax has nothing to do with it or Ajax.

Comment: and your question is very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46828614/how-to-add-spinner-loader-in-yii2-php) i wonder which one i should answer :P , or you can close your question in the other quedtion's favour if you think its the similar situation and i will add an answer there if none others work

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam this one is original ;), also I did try to implement a [soluiton](http://www.marcorpsa.com/ee/t2228.html). Now I am able to see a loading screen but I am getting `null` at `isset($_POST['dco'])`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I have added the updates about what I have tried

Comment: added an answer fo you see if it works

Comment: Can you mark the answer that worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### My Understanding

Looking at your current implementation you are using normal form submission although wrapped inside the `Pjax` container but you haven't enabled form submission via `Pjax` for your form and want to show a spinner or loader that would show until the request to the action where you are sending the `curl` request to some API completes.

#### Limitations

Something you need to understand is that if you are making normal form submission and trying to show a spinner for some process that you are doing inside your `controller/action` won't work as the view is not rendered yet and your spinner related any `javascript` or `CSS` isn't rendered in the browser yet and won't show.

## Solution

On the other hand, if you use `ajax` or `pjax` for your form submissions as you already have wrapped your form inside the `Pjax` container you can use the `Pjax` events with enabling a spinner from the [AdminBSBTheme](https://gurayyarar.github.io/AdminBSBMaterialDesign/) which uses CSS only to show the spinner.

That won't just work for your ajax forms but you can use it overall the site for normal page loads leaving a nice effect. It automatically hides once the `DOM` is ready, in case of slow internet connections it makes things look more aligned.

**Enable Pjax on Form**

You have to add `data-pjax="1"` attribute in the form tag to enable `Pjax` form submission it won't work by default, so go ahead and change the following line to enable `Pjax` submission for the form.

```
<?php echo Html::beginForm(['process'],'post', ['data' => ['pjax' => 1]);?>
```

**Enable Timeout for Pjax**

Then you need to specify the `timeout` parameter property if your `curl` request takes a bit of time it's better to add high value for the `timeout` property so that it won't throw `loading request failed` or `timeout` error and waits for the response. Let us give it `10 seconds` so if the request takes up to `10 secs` to complete it should keep waiting otherwise continue if the response received

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['timeout'=>10000]); ?>
```

**Spinner Integration**

Now comes the part of the spinner integration you can see it running in the demo below it is pure CSS based.

Copy the `Html` from the demo below in your `views\layouts\main.php` file after `$this->beginBody()` and
add the `css` inside your `site.css` file or, create a separate file and include in the `AppAssets.php` file.

```css
/ Page Loader ================================= /

.page-loader-wrapper {
  z-index: 99999999;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.page-loader-wrapper p {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #444;
}

.page-loader-wrapper .loader {
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50% - 30px);
}


/ Preloaders ================================== /

.md-preloader .pl-red {
  stroke: #F44336;
}

.md-preloader .pl-pink {
  stroke: #E91E63;
}

.md-preloader .pl-purple {
  stroke: #9C27B0;
}

.md-preloader .pl-deep-purple {
  stroke: #673AB7;
}

.md-preloader .pl-indigo {
  stroke: #3F51B5;
}

.md-preloader .pl-blue {
  stroke: #2196F3;
}

.md-preloader .pl-light-blue {
  stroke: #03A9F4;
}

.md-preloader .pl-cyan {
  stroke: #00BCD4;
}

.md-preloader .pl-teal {
  stroke: #009688;
}

.md-preloader .pl-green {
  stroke: #4CAF50;
}

.md-preloader .pl-light-green {
  stroke: #8BC34A;
}

.md-preloader .pl-lime {
  stroke: #CDDC39;
}

.md-preloader .pl-yellow {
  stroke: #ffe821;
}

.md-preloader .pl-amber {
  stroke: #FFC107;
}

.md-preloader .pl-orange {
  stroke: #FF9800;
}

.md-preloader .pl-deep-orange {
  stroke: #FF5722;
}

.md-preloader .pl-brown {
  stroke: #795548;
}

.md-preloader .pl-grey {
  stroke: #9E9E9E;
}

.md-preloader .pl-blue-grey {
  stroke: #607D8B;
}

.md-preloader .pl-black {
  stroke: #000000;
}

.md-preloader .pl-white {
  stroke: #ffffff;
}

.preloader {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-animation: container-rotate 1568ms linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: container-rotate 1568ms linear infinite;
  -o-animation: container-rotate 1568ms linear infinite;
  animation: container-rotate 1568ms linear infinite;
}

.preloader.pl-size-xl {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}

.preloader.pl-size-l {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

.preloader.pl-size-md {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.preloader.pl-size-sm {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.preloader.pl-size-xs {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.spinner-layer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-color: #F44336;
  -ms-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
  -moz-animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
  -o-animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
  animation: fill-unfill-rotate 5332ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-red {
  border-color: #F44336;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-pink {
  border-color: #E91E63;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-purple {
  border-color: #9C27B0;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-deep-purple {
  border-color: #673AB7;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-indigo {
  border-color: #3F51B5;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-blue {
  border-color: #2196F3;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-light-blue {
  border-color: #03A9F4;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-cyan {
  border-color: #00BCD4;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-teal {
  border-color: #009688;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-green {
  border-color: #4CAF50;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-light-green {
  border-color: #8BC34A;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-lime {
  border-color: #CDDC39;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-yellow {
  border-color: #ffe821;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-amber {
  border-color: #FFC107;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-orange {
  border-color: #FF9800;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-deep-orange {
  border-color: #FF5722;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-brown {
  border-color: #795548;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-grey {
  border-color: #9E9E9E;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-blue-grey {
  border-color: #607D8B;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-black {
  border-color: #000000;
}

.spinner-layer.pl-white {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}

.right {
  float: right !important;
}

.gap-patch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 45%;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-color: inherit;
}

.gap-patch.circle {
  width: 1000%;
  left: -450%;
}

.circle-clipper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-color: inherit;
}

.circle-clipper .circle {
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: inherit;
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: none;
  animation: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.circle-clipper.left .circle {
  left: 0;
  border-right-color: transparent !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(129deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(129deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(129deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(129deg);
  transform: rotate(129deg);
  -webkit-animation: left-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
  -moz-animation: left-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
  -o-animation: left-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
  animation: left-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
}

.circle-clipper.right .circle {
  left: -100%;
  border-left-color: transparent !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-129deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-129deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-129deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-129deg);
  transform: rotate(-129deg);
  -webkit-animation: right-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
  -moz-animation: right-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
  -o-animation: right-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
  animation: right-spin 1333ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) infinite both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes container-rotate {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes container-rotate {
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fill-unfill-rotate {
  12.5% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
  37.5% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(405deg);
    transform: rotate(405deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(540deg);
    transform: rotate(540deg);
  }
  62.5% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(675deg);
    transform: rotate(675deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(810deg);
    transform: rotate(810deg);
  }
  87.5% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(945deg);
    transform: rotate(945deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1080deg);
    transform: rotate(1080deg);
  }
}

@keyframes fill-unfill-rotate {
  12.5% {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
  37.5% {
    transform: rotate(405deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(540deg);
  }
  62.5% {
    transform: rotate(675deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(810deg);
  }
  87.5% {
    transform: rotate(945deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(1080deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes left-spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(130deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(130deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(130deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(130deg);
    transform: rotate(130deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(130deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(130deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(130deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(130deg);
    transform: rotate(130deg);
  }
}

@keyframes left-spin {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(130deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(130deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(130deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(130deg);
    transform: rotate(130deg);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(130deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(130deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(130deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(130deg);
    transform: rotate(130deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes right-spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    transform: rotate(-130deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(5deg);
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    transform: rotate(-130deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes right-spin {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    transform: rotate(-130deg);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    transform: rotate(-130deg);
  }
}

@keyframes right-spin {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    transform: rotate(-130deg);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-130deg);
    transform: rotate(-130deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Page Loader -->
<div class="page-loader-wrapper">
  <div class="loader">
    <div class="preloader">
      <div class="spinner-layer pl-red">
        <div class="circle-clipper left">
          <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="circle-clipper right">
          <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Please wait...</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- #END# Page Loader -->
```

Then add the following on top of the `views\layouts\main.php` file

```
$js = <<<JS
     setTimeout(function () {
        $('.page-loader-wrapper').fadeOut();
    }, 50);
JS;
$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

**Note: Ideally you can wrap everything related to the spinner in a separate asset file and call it in the main layout, but I will leave that part to you.**

Until this point, if you try to click any of the links on your application you will see the spinner working for your normal page loads like the home page about or any other.

**Enabling for Pjax requests**

We need to enable it for the `Pjax` too, so go to your `view` file and add the following piece of javascript on top which uses the [`pjax:beforeSend`](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#events) event to show the spinner

```
$js = <<<JS
$(document).on("pjax:beforeSend",function(){
    $('.page-loader-wrapper').fadeIn();
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

You don't need to worry about closing the spinner it would be closed once the page is loaded after the curl response via our main Layout code.

**Update**

The reason why the submit button value isn't submitted when using pjax is a known issue, see [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/3719). What you can do about it is to add 2 hidden fields for the 2 submit buttons and updated the value of the respective hidden field associated with the button when clicked and submit them along with the form and check the value for those new hidden inputs, so that you can identify which button was clicked.

So, first we will add hidden inputs, note the options used for the original `submitButton` rco and dco the id should be there.

```
<?php echo Html::beginForm(['about'], 'post', ['data' => ['pjax' => 1]]); ?>
<?php echo Html::submitButton('Disconnect', ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'id' => 'dco']) ?>
<?php echo Html::submitButton('Connect', ['class' => 'btn btn-info', 'id' => 'rco']) ?>
<?php echo Html::hiddenInput('dco', '', ['id' => 'dco_input']); ?>
<?php echo Html::hiddenInput('rco', '', ['id' => 'rco_input']); ?>
```

Now we will replace the javascript that we added before in our view wiith the following

```
$js = <<<JS

    function loader(){
        $('.page-loader-wrapper').fadeOut();
        //reset the input values
        $("#dco_input,#rco_input").val('');

        //assign respective values to the associated hidden fields
        $("#rco,#dco").on('click',function(e){
            var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');
            $("#"+buttonId+"_input").val(1);
        });
    }
    
    $(document).on("pjax:beforeSend",function(e){
        $('.page-loader-wrapper').fadeIn();
    }).on("pjax:end",function(){
        loader();
    });
    loader();
JS;
    $this->registerJs($js, View::POS_READY);
?>
```

Now whenever we will click the `dco` submit button the hidden input `dco_input` will be populated with `1` and when the `rco` submit button is clicked `rco_input` will be updated with value `1` before the for is submitted and you will receive the value in post for both the buttons.

The last thing you need to change are the checks in your controller/action  `process()`, which are checking `isset($_POST['dco'])` and `isset($_POST['rco'])` which will not work and need to be updated

```
if(isset($_POST['dco']))
```

with

```
if(isset($_POST["dco"]) && $_POST['dco']==1)
```

and

```
if(isset($_POST['rco']))
```

with

```
if(isset($_POST['rco']) && $_POST['rco']==1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful solution. I am able to see the spinner now. But unable to perform the process as I am getting `bool(false)` at `var_dump(isset($_POST['dco']));`

Comment: what data does console show you posted against the request

Comment: It doesn't show anything the page was just redirected and it didn't hit the `if (isset($_POST['dco']))`

Comment: can you share me the application url

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$this->registerJs(<<<JS
$(document).on('pjax:send', function() {
   $('#loading').show();
});
$(document).on('pjax:complete', function() {
  $('#loading').hide();
});
JS
);
?>
```

example: with fontawesome( or can use image ....)

```
<i id='loading' class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse' style='display:none;'></i>
```

You can also do this by a variable (in the controller).

Comment: Read the comment before.  Place the **html** and **registerJs** (Top codes) in the VIEW file(GridView) and then delete your javascript code. I mean `event.preventDefault () .....` Now test the  top **loading**  By **submitButton** (Send **form** by **pjax**)

Comment: You are right . data-pjax should be empty (`data-pjax' => ''`). It is not possible to receive the submitButton id for your code.  I put another post. Test the code. I hope this helps. Otherwise, use the idea of @Muhammad Omer Aslam